# Where are perl modules located in archlinux

Tags: perl, perl-module, archlinux

Im trying to find perl modules, such as strict and warnings, but i cant find them... btw im actually using archlinux, i tried using

```
whereis
```

but it throws nothing.

Answer (score 4):

If the module has POD documentation embedded (which most do), the following will display its location:

```
perldoc -l Some::Module   (Lowercase "L" for "location")
```

Otherwise, you can use

```
perl -E'use Some::Module; say $INC{"Some/Module.pm"};'
```

---

You might be interested in identifying all the locations in which your Perl searches for modules. If so, look at the contents of `@INC`. You can use

```
perl -V                 (Uppercase "V")
```

or

```
perl -E'say for @INC;'
```

You may also be interested in [Devel::Modlist](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Devel%3a%3aModlist). The following will lists the path to all the modules used (directly or indirectly) by a script or module:

```
perl -d:Modlist=path some_script.pl

perl -d:Modlist=path -e'use Some::Module;'
```

Without `=path`, it returns the versions of all the modules.

Comment: @Josh, Added reference to Devel::Modlist.

Answer (score 1):

To find an individual module:

```
perldoc -l warnings
```

All modules are under `@INC` directories:

```
perl -V
```

See also: [Find installed Perl modules matching a regular expression](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=795418)

Answer (score 1):

The `%INC` hash holds the on-disk locations of loaded modules, keyed by the package name. You can step through the keys of `%INC` and print out the associated value. For example:

```
$ perl -MData::Dump -e 'print "$_: $INC{$_}\n" foreach keys %INC'
```

(I loaded Data::Dump so that at least one module would be pulled in for sure. You don't have to load that specific module yourself.)

Also, the `@INC` array holds the include paths that `perl` searches for modules in, so you can always do:

```
$ perl -E 'say foreach @INC'
```

To find all the default include paths.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a Linux distribution, the native package manager is the most suitable tool. In this case, it's highly recommend to use pacman for such a task:

```
pacman -Ql perl | egrep '(strict|warnings).pm'
```